# QGIS: Waypoint name (symbol label) in two rows

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have couple of longer waypoints names that I would like to put in two rows with center formatting but I just don't know how? I tried to put 
 tag but it doesn't help...

For example I have the waypoint with name 'one two three five six seven' and I want to make it like this:

```
one two 
three five six seven
```